# Using Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2022

[Source Control Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-source-control-explorer-manage-files-under-version-control?view=azure-devops) is what I have used in the past to manage my Team Foundation version control (TFVC).

In Visual Studio 2019 (and earlier verions), you could open Source Control Explorer by navigating to **View | Other Windows | Source Control Explorer**.  However, this window can't be found here in VS2022.

Has this functionality been completely removed or is there still a way to access Source Control Explorer using Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow below steps to add the TFS server:

- **Manage Connections -> Connect to a project** option in the Team Explorer (use View -> Team Explorer if not available) and connect to the project.
- Click **Add Azure DevOps Server**, input tfs server URL and choose **Add**.
- Then the list of projects you have access will be listed below, select a project and connect.

Then the **Source control** menu option will be made **available** in the usual place View | Other Windows | Source Control Explorer.

These are the steps from **Visual Studio Professional 2022**

Use **Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2022** only when Visual studio Developer not installed.

Comment: I had to click 'Manage' (the green plug) to connect to my AzDo instance.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the [Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/connect-team-project?view=vs-2019).

See also [Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/compatibility):

> Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2022 will connect to Azure DevOps Server 2019, Team Foundation Server 2017, Team Foundation Server 2015, Team Foundation Server 2013, Team Foundation Server 2012, and Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Clone Repository > Team Explorer > Manage connections.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cloud Explorer which is in Visual studio 2019 as shown below, has been **retired in Visual Studio 2022**

[image]

Instead, we can use the following alternatives mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-resources-managing-with-cloud-explorer?view=vs-2022

Comment: You seem to have posted a valid answer, but it lacks something important. A link to another site could be not enough for our quality standards. Instead if you post a succint explanation of what could be found on the link posted then we can be sure that your answer will be useful even if the link disappears